# How do I read ID's from an li and pass them into C# code behind?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a ul with 10 li's which the user has populated through jquery sortable. Each li has a hidden span with the ID in it. How do I read the IDs and pass them into my C# code behind when the user clicks an ASP.NET button?

Here is my thought process:

1. Build a jquery function that loops and retrieves all the IDs and passes them into an array.
2. Pass only the array back to C#.
3. In my code behind: read the array and do whatever I need from there.

My problem:

1. I don't know what jquery is involved to create the array
2. I don't know how to pass the array to the code behind
3. I don't know how to read the array in my code behind

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span id="competencyID">3</span>

    <h1><span id="competencyTitle">Comp Title</span></h1>   

</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <span id="competencyID">18</span>

    <h1><span id="competencyTitle">Comp Title</span></h1>   

</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <span id="competencyID">103</span>

    <h1><span id="competencyTitle">Comp Title</span></h1>   

</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <span id="competencyID">6</span>

    <h1><span id="competencyTitle">Comp Title</span></h1>   

</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <span id="competencyID">25</span>

    <h1><span id="competencyTitle">Comp Title</span></h1>   

</li>
```

Comment: You could also use hidden form fields instead of spans, then you can just read them on the server like any other form input.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the $.get callback function and I still don't know how to read the array in C# whenever I figure that out :/ But I'm getting there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make id's unique, I would replace the id's of the `<span>` tags with classes.

Change:

```
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <span id="competencyID">25</span>

    <h1><span id="competencyTitle">Comp Title</span></h1>   

</li>
```

To:

```
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="competencyID">25</span>

    <h1><span class="competencyTitle">Comp Title</span></h1>   

</li>
```

For your jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$('#button_id').bind('click', function () {
    var arr = {};//create new object (empty)
    $('#ul_id').find('.competencyID').each(function (index, value) {
        arr[index] = $(value).text();
    });
    //send data to server-side script
    $.get('path/to_server.file', $.param(arr), function (response) {
        //this is the callback function, once your server-side script runs you can output data that you can retrieve here via the response variable
    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle of collecting the id's and adding them to a JavaScript object: http://jsfiddle.net/rre47/1/

**--UPDATE--**

If you want to return an array of ids that can more easily be parsed by server-side scripts you can use the following code:

Change:

`var arr = {};` to `var arr = {'id' : []};`

And Change:

`$.param(arr)` to `decodeURIComponent($.param(arr))`

The output will look like this:

```
id[]=3&id[]=18&id[]=103&id[]=6&id[]=25
```

jsfiddle of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/rre47/4/

Comment: +1: Really nice solution, but JSON might be easier to parse in code-behind. If you revised your answer to build the array with JSON, that would be really slick.

Comment: @Jasper- The CompetencyID is a must since I'm populating this ul through an asp.net repeater. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jasper- Would you provide an example of retrieving the array in C#?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with C#, but a quick Google search looked promising: http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+querystring+array

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

You can do a web method and call it in javascript, when you call it you can pass javascript variable.

You will then get you javascript variables in the code behind.

For the loop you can do :

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Hidden fields instead of spans to store data that must go to the server:

```
<input type="hidden" name="competencyTitle" value="Comp Title" />
```

These hidden fields can be read in the server using the `Request.Params` property:

```
var value = Request.Params["competencyTitle"];
```